# Laravel 5.2 : Error Exeption:[object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am new to `Ajax` I was following tutorial to send data to `db` using `Ajax`

here is my form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/blog', 'method'=>'post', 'files'=>'true')) !!}
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('title', 'Title') !!}
                {!! Form::text('title', '', array('placeholder'=>'Blog title', 'class'=>'form-control')) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('paragraph', 'Blog Content') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('paragraph', '', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Paragraph...', 'rows'=>3)) !!}
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace('paragraph', {
                        uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
                        stylesSet: 'my_custom_style'
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('image', 'Main Image') !!}
                {!! Form::file('image') !!}
                <p class="help-block">Please review the upload instructions in 'Reminder!'</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-footer">
            {!! Form::submit('Add', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'onClick'=>'send(event)')) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and this is the `Ajax` I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function send(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ 'admin/blog' }}",
                data: {
                    title: $("#title").val(),
                    paragraph: $("#paragraph").val(),
                    image: $("#image").val(),
                    _token: "{{ Session::token() }}"
                },
                success:function(result)//we got the response
                {
                    alert('Successfully called');
                },
                error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
            })

        }
    </script>
```

and here is the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'paragraph' => 'required|min:100',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png',
        ]);
        $add = new Blog();

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($image)->resize(600, 390)->save(public_path('images/blog/' . $filename));
            Image::make($image)->fit(335, 219)->save(public_path('images/blog/thumbs-' . $filename));
            $add->image = $filename;
        }

        $add->title = $request->title;
        $add->paragraph = $request->paragraph;
        $add->addBy = \Auth::user()->name;
        $add->save();

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json();
        }
        return \Redirect::back();
    }
```

when I try to click `add` I got

> Error Exeption:[object Object]

**Edit**
In my routes I was using `resource` add new `Route` with `POST method`

```
Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
Route::post('blog', 'BlogController@store');
```

Changed the Ajax `URL` and the error results

```
url: "{{ url('admin/blog/store') }}",
error:function(exception){console.log(exception)}
```

in my console got this error

> Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader:
>   .ajax/x.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders:
>   .ajax/x.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader:
>   .ajax/x.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType:
>   .ajax/x.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/x.statusCode(), abort:
>   .ajax/x.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always:
>   .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 more… }

Comment: In this line: `alert('Exeption:'+exception)` exception is an object. Hence it's coerced to a string when you alert it - this is why `alert()` is not a good idea when debugging. Use `console.log(exception)` instead and you should hopefully have some useful information to help diagnose the problem

Comment: Can you explicit the error message you get please? Where is it? What object?

Comment: Replace `alert('Exeption:'+exception);` with `console.log('Exeption:'+exception)` . Then send the log so we can help you

Comment: @AhmadRezk I have replaced the line to be `error:function(exception){console.log('Exeption:'+exception)}` but I didn't get any response no error where should I get this `log` from

Comment: If you use Firefox, install Firebug Addon and press F12 to open debugger

Comment: @AhmadRezk I did and I found this `<span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException">NotFoundHttpException</abbr> in <a title="C:\wamp\www\meshwebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php line 161" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">RouteCollection.php line 161</a>:</span>` I understood it not found and the request url was `http://localhost:8000/admin/blog/admin/blog` which should be `http://localhost:8000/admin/blog`

Comment: @YousefAltaf Why the request is admin/blog/admin/blog ?

Comment: @YousefAltaf `readyState: 4` means that your request is done.
Please check your response tab in debugger to check for server side errors

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, solved by JSON.stringify(dataObject) before sending AJAX request.